# Using xCopy to create entire folder structure, including root folder name and all files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, xcopy

I looked at quite a few solutions to `xCopy` questions, and tried many difference
methods.  (Various wildcards, paths ending in \, various `xcopy` switches in various combinations.)

```
xCopy c:\Public  d:\MyNewDir\
```

When done, I need the destination to include a folder called "Public" with containing all files, folders, subfolders, everything.

The result should will look like:

```
d:\MyNewDir\Public\(and everything inside it)
```

Not like this:

```
d:\MyNewDir\(everything inside Public)
```

That sounds so simple.  Instead, I never see a "Public" folder created.  It only creates everything WITHIN "Public".... but never "Public" itself.
(I have many folders to copy, so I don't want to create folders individual, manually.)

Is there a solution to this simple issue using only xCopy and Windows 7?

Comment: It doesn't appear that copy/xcopy/robocopy support this basic feature... Maybe powershell.. or use %~n1 for destination (%1 being argument to script) see: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Percent_tilde
robocopy /z /e /mt %1 D:\Backups\%~n1\

Answer (score 9):

#### I need the destination to include a folder called "Public"

> containing all files, folders, subfolders, everything.

Use the following command:

```
xcopy c:\Public\* d:\MyNewDir\Public /s /i
```

- `/s` - Copy folders and subfolders
- `/i` - If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder
       e.g. when the destination does not exist.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.

Comment: If there are a lot of (small) files it might be a good idea to use the `/Q` option (*"Do not display file names while copying."*). At the end of the copy process it will output something like "`122546 File(s) copied`".

Comment: I'm going mad. Again it's not copying the root directory for me

Comment: I've succeeded with [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.3#example-3-copy-directory-and-contents-to-a-new-directory)

Answer (score 1):

1st, enumerate folder structure into a file:

```
dir /ad /b /s C:\ > D:\windir.txt
```

2nd, open `D:\windir.txt` in Notepad and replace all `C:\` with null; save file

3rd, use `for` command to recurse through `windir.txt`
to copy directory structure and files in each directory:

```
for /f "delims=;" %a in (D:\windir.txt) do xcopy "C:\%a" "D:\MyNewDir\%a" /c /i /g /h /k /o /x /j /b /y
```

You can add `/q` if you don't want to see the directories and files as they're being copied; I like the positive feedback.